# Why does @INC change when setgid-bit of C wrapper around perl script change?

Tags: c, linux, perl, permissions

This is all on RHEL6

I am trying to run a perl script as a specific user (owner of the perl script) by wrapping it inside a C binary and then setting the setgid bit of the binary (ref: https://superuser.com/questions/440363/can-i-make-a-script-always-execute-as-root). The perl script uses various perl modules.  If the perl modules are in PERL5LIB of the account trying to run the C binary, and the setgid-bit is NOT set on the C binary, it runs fine.  If the setgid-bit IS set, then it fails because the used perl modules are not in @INC.

Some code to demo how @INC changes with the sticky bit...

the.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "Size of INC: ".scalar(@INC)."\n";
exit;
```

wrapper.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  exit(execvp("/home/me/the.pl",(char **)argv));
}
```

The perl script permissions are -rwxrwxr-x

When I set the wrapper's permissions to -rwxr-xr-x (note the setgid bit is not set), then run the binary from some other account, I get...

```
Size of INC = 87
```

...which is what I would expect (there are 87 elements in PERL5LIB).

But when I set the wrapper's permissions to -rwxr-sr-x (note the setgid bit is set), then run the binary from some other account, I get...

```
Size of INC = 4
```

I get the same results even if I load PERL5LIB with all 87 elements in the .cshrc of both the perl script's owner and that of the account that's running the wrapper.

I need to run the binary as the owner of the perl script because that account has a priv that the user's accounts don't have.  The root user is not a player in any of this.

Why am I losing those PERL5LIB elements?
Is there a way I can get around this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you really need *eighty-seven* locations in `@INC`? That's a hell of a lot and the build is going to be very inefficient.

Comment: Don't use a wrapper like in the linked answer! That's crazy dangerous!!! Set the setuid/setgid bit on the script itself instead. (Alternate method 1 mentioned in the linked answer)

Answer (score 8):

A setuid perl script is run in taint mode, and [perlsec](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsec#Taint-mode-and-@INC) says:

> When the taint mode ("`-T`") is in effect, **the "`.`" directory is removed
>          from `@INC`, and the environment variables "`PERL5LIB`" and "`PERLLIB`" are
>          ignored by Perl**. You can still adjust `@INC` from outside the program by
>          using the "`-I`" command line option as explained in `perlrun`. The two
>          environment variables are ignored because they are obscured, and a user
>          running a program could be unaware that they are set, whereas the "`-I`"
>          option is clearly visible and therefore permitted.

If you cannot adjust `@INC` inside the program (say, with `use lib ...`), you will want to rewrite your C program to call the `perl` executable instead of your script name, and to prepend `argv` with your script name and any appropriate `-I...` arguments that you want to use.

Comment: @daveg, You should have someone review your code for insecurities; you're skirting with multiple major security violations. For starters, mob forgot to mention the directories in `@INC` and the files in those directories should only be writable by the impersonated user.