# How does one pass includes to execvp that's running a perl script?

Tags: c, perl

RHEL6

In C, how does one pass includes to execvp which in turn runs a perl executable ? (this is a means to replace missing translation of PERL5LIB to @INC when taint mode is on)

This question is looking for a working implementation of an answer provided by mob to...
[Why does @INC change when setgid-bit of C wrapper around perl script change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516416/why-does-inc-change-when-setgid-bit-of-c-wrapper-around-perl-script-change).

I'm wrapping a perl script execution in a C program that uses execvp to call the perl.  Because taint mode is enabled, @INC will not be loaded with the content of $PERL5LIB, so I have pass the paths to the perl executable using "-I".  perlsec says this is possible (ref the answer provided by mob in the note sited above).

My attempts to do this have failed.  My C program attempted to run the perl executable as the first arg to execvp and then the perl script as part of the argument list.  The includes were made part of the perl script executable statement.  Here's the example...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char **args;  /*args will be passed to execvp.  prepend perl executable*/

  args=malloc(3*sizeof(char*));

  args[0]=malloc(sizeof("/tools/bin/perl -I/proj/perlmods")+1);
  strcpy(args[0],"/tools/bin/perl -I/proj/perlmods");

  args[1]=malloc(sizeof("/home/me/the.pl")+1);
  strcpy(args[1],"/home/me/the.pl");

  args[2]=NULL;

  execvp("/tools/bin/perl",args);

}
```

The perl script is simply...

```
use html_mail;
print "In my.pl\n";
exit;
```

/proj/perlmods has html_mail.pm

A straight out perl execution at the linux prompt using -I works...

```
% /tools/bin/perl -I /proj/perlmods /home/me/my.pl
In my.pl
```

But running the C binary does not.  It complains that the perl module can't be found.  If, however, /proj/perlmods is put in PERL5LIB, then it does work.  So I think args is good as far as the perl script being in args[1].

I believe the include statement I threw into args is being ignored.  If I stick it as a suffix to the perl executable call in the execvp...

```
  execvp("/tools/bin/perl -I /proj/perlmods",args);
```

...the C program fails, so I don't think it belongs there.  If I put the include as part of the perl script call....

```
  strcpy(args[1],"/home/me/the.pl -I /proj/perlmods");
```

... it fails.  If I add it as a new element of args (args[3]), it just gets passed as an arg to the perl script and has no affect.

I looked at execvpe, but that just looks like a means to set env vars.

Question is, how does one actually pass the include information to the execvp ?

Comment: If `execvp` fails, then `errno` is set. Add a `perror("execvp")` after `execvp` to see why it's failing.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof("/home/me/the.pl") == strlen("/home/me/the.pl") + 1`, because `"/home/me/the.pl"` is a string literal.

Answer (score 5):

You need each argument to be a separate entry in `args`. Try this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *args[4];       /* args will be passed to execvp.  prepend perl executable */

    args[0] = "/tools/bin/perl";
    args[1] = "-I/proj/perlmods";
    args[2] = "/home/me/the.pl";
    args[3] = NULL;

    execvp(args[0], args);

}
```

Comment: I tried this. It works if the sticky-bit on the C binary isn't set, but fails if it does.  If it's set, then it runs in taint mode, and despite the documentation, running the perl executable with -I <lib> alone isn't good enough.  This may be another security roadblock.  Explicitly listing the libs in the perl source with "use lib" does work but defeats the dynamicity of PERL5LIB. At this point I feel like I'm trying to hack around security roadblocks.  I think I'm going to back off and seek a different angle.  Thanks for all the help !  Hope this helps others.

Comment: @daveg, As I previously pointed out, you are talking about the setuid bit, not the setuid bit.

Comment: I've had to do this before (e.g. setuid launch of `perl` script). When you setup a setuid program (e.g. changing ownership to root and doing `chmod 6741 ...`), it will only set euid (effective user id) to 0/root and _not_ uid (real user id). `perl` will see uid!=0 and euid==0 and set taint mode. Have the launcher program do `setuid(0)` and `setgid(0)` so that `perl` sees everything as root and it won't complain. Not sure, but the setuid program _may_ wipe some of the environment, so you may need the launcher to set up the environment variables (e.g. `PERL5LIB`, etc.)

Comment: (uh, my prev comment should be "you are talking about the setuid bit, not the sticky bit")

Comment: @Craig Estey, Trying to fool Perl into using the caller's PERL5LIB is an awful idea. It *should* be ignored, as not ignoring it would allow the caller to run arbitrary code as root.

Comment: @ikegami I've had to do this in production code. It's up to the [setuid] launcher to do restrictions. If you can establish a setuid program, you can do whatever you want because you're already root. This can be used for embedded systems that want to run [mostly] as non-root but still have to run some perl scripts [or apps] as root.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mean reusing the parent's PERL5LIB. Fine. Still crazy to use an insecure C wrapper instead of using `use lib`.

Comment: @ikegami Right, the setuid must prevent misuse but prevent `perl` from complaining. It's like `sudo` without the pw prompt, which is unsuitable if you have to do `sudo`-like things on an unattended/embedded system. I wrote my first setuid program circa 1993 [or earlier] and has a `/etc/*.conf` file that listed restrictions (i.e. _"I was doing sudo before sudo was cool"_ ;-). The concept has been around since the 1970's: access by secure program and was available on an IBM/370 OS I used/programmed. Any file could designate a _program_ that could access it with what permissions, like an ACL.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing something wrong if you're using `-I`. The script's executer shouldn't have to care about where the script's libraries are located.

- If `/proj/perlmods` is used by multiple applications, you should add the following to your login script:

  ```
  export PERL5LIB=/proj/perlmods
  ```
- If `/proj/perlmods` is only used by that one Perl program, add the following to the Perl program:

  ```
  use lib qw( /proj/perlmods );
  ```

Then, the C program becomes

```
char *args[2];                  # Or char **args = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
args[0] = "/home/me/the.pl";    # No need to duplicate the string; just copy the ptr.
args[1] = NULL;

execvp(args[0], args);
```

instead of

```
char *args[4];                  # Or char **args = malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
args[0] = "/tools/bin/perl";
args[1] = "-I/proj/perlmods";
args[2] = "/home/me/the.pl";
args[3] = NULL;

execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: This works, but static defs of the libs in the perl source doesn't fit our model of using $PERL5LIB as a dynamic set of libs set up in the env.  Using the C wrapper which could echo the content of $PERL5LIB as includes would work (in theory), but it appears they threw up other security roadblocks to prevent that.

Comment: @daveg, NO NO NO, don't use `PERL5LIB`. You'll let the initial user run any code as the setuid user! You should definitely be using `use lib` in a setuid situation. (And get rid of the C wrapper, as I previously mentioned.)